# Implementing a news feed system in Java EE and jquery

Tags: java, jquery, feed

I am going to implement a news feed notification system where I will show new items on my webpage. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8ND53/.

I will be calling a Servlet say every 5 seconds to get updates and the servlet will return items in json format. That seems very simple, but how do I manage that all on the server side?

What I think is:

- I have to keep track of the last item (by date) sent to a user so that next time I can fetch new items from the DB.

Is their any standard way of doing such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea!

I will assume that you make a bean, dao and service layers from your db table that contains the feeds.

---

At first moment when the page that will retrieve the feeds loads, get all your feeds from a java function and then fill your div with your feeds.

Get the feeds count from your feed container. Now pass the count through jQuery `$.post` and then to your servlet. To achive this, do the following:

e.g:

```
//Find divs inside the parent div that will contain your feeds
function getCount(){
  return $('#feedContainer').children().find('div').size().toString();
}

//Don't forget to pass it to your jQuery post like this 
//(Please, continue reading to understand where to put this)
$.post('/servlet', count:getCount(), function(data){ //manage your new feeds });
```

Your servlet will receive something like this:

e.g:

```
String count = request.getParameter("count");
```

Now that you have the count, verify or just parse as an `Integer` and then do a list in java. I suppose you have a function to get all your feeds from DB.

e.g:

```
//Parse it as integer
int feedCountFromUI = Integer.valueOf(count);

//Do a list and call your function to get all feeds from DB.
MyService myService = new MyService();
List<MyBean> feeds = myService.getAll();

//JSON variable
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

//Fill your JSON variable
for(MyBean mb : feeds) {
   //Build a json with your feeds and fill result
}
```

Suppose that now you have a JSON Object variable called `result` in your servlet with your feed values filled in the `for` done above. Now get the count from your list declared as `feeds` (from above too).

```
int feedCountFromDB = feeds.size();
```

You are now close to finish, compare the 2 counts. If the `feedCountFromDB` it's more than the `feedCountFromUI`, means that there are new feeds to load.

```
if(feedCountFromDB > feedCountFromUI){
  //Send your json variable (result) to your jquery post callback
  out.println(result);
} else {
  //Means there is nothing new, print 0
  out.println(0);
}
```

At this point you just need to fill your feed container with the last feed every 5 seconds like this:

*(You can add also your jQuery animate function from your jsFiddle at this point)*

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.post('/servlet', count:getCount(), function(data){ 
     //If data has feeds (it's not 0)
     if(data != 0) {
       var lastFeed = data[data.length - 1];
       $('#feedContainer').append('<div>' + lastFeed.title + '<br/>' +   lastFeed.description + '</div>';
     }
  });
}, 5000);
```

This will always check the count from your web interface and then compare it with the count from DB each 5 seconds to get your new feed.

Hope this helps :-)